# Replace all occurrences in Javascript based on Regex with dynamic string

Tags: javascript, regex

In my ruby script I have a regex :

```
             regex = /(^|[^\d])\d{8,15}(?!\d)/g;
```

and a string

```
        var str="jshbfjhsgf 123 1234567890 4567890123 hhrrwt";
```

If I do

```
        str.replace(regex,"xxxxxxxxxx");
```

Output will be  :

```
         "jshbfjhsgf 123 xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx hhrrwt";
```

But I want something like this :

```
        "jshbfjhsgf 123 1xxxxxxxx0 4xxxxxxxx3 hhrrwt";
```

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic range with [Regex(string, string)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor:

```js
function digitMask(min, max, str, replacement) {
    var regex = new RegExp("(^|[^\\d])(\\d)(\\d{" + min + "," + max + "})(\\d)(?!\\d)","g");
    return str.replace(regex, function (match, c1, c2, c3, c4, index, source) {
        var length = c3.length;
        var mask = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) mask += replacement;
        return match.replace(c3, mask);
    });
}

    var result =  digitMask(8, 14, "start 123 1234567890123123567890 4567890123 end", "-");
    console.log(result)
    // outputs "start 123 1--------------3 4--------3 end"
```

The second and fourth, single digit captures, groups allow the inner capture and masking with respect to the length of the inner capture.

Comment: Hard coded solution. What if the amount of digits is different?

Comment: Kind user, oh yeah. I updated the answer with a method.

Comment: @Joe this is not issue ...i want number of x to be printed the number of char  in matched in regex -2. eg if my string contains 12345678901234 ,in output i want 1XXXXXXXXXXXX4

Comment: @Joe. it still has one issue..it will also replace in substrings where number of digits exceed 14..it will be something like this 1XXXXXXXXXXXX67890

Comment: @Joe check this        digitMask(8, 14, "start 123 1234567890123123567890 4567890123 end", "-");

Comment: Groovy, I forgot I removed the look ahead. (?!\d) added it back